Looking for a Reliable, Maintenance-Free Backup Solution for Ubuntu 24.04
I'm looking for recommendations on a reliable, easy-to-manage backup solution for my Ubuntu 24.04 system. My goal is to backup about 150GB of data, including files, images, and documents.
My data is currently split between cloud services such as OneDrive and Google Photos, plus some stored locally. I'm exploring offline backup options that also allow for easy portability and give me peace of mind having all the data in one place if ever needed.
In a perfect world, I'd love a backup utility that can hook into the cloud services and pull down copies as well as backup my local data. I realize this may not be possible, so I'm willing to manually download everything and back it up locally.

Data Size: Approximately 150GB
External Hardware: SSD with USB 3.0 connection
Usage: Mainly browser-based activities. I do not need to backup the OS or applications, as I can reinstall these if necessary.
Backup Type: Offline, using my external SSD
Bonus Points: Ability to integrate with OneDrive and Google Photos, which has been challenging with GNOME on Ubuntu. I'd love to automatically pull down my Google photos that gets uploaded by family phones, and new onedrive docs, and back them up too
Functionality: Automated backups with little to no manual intervention required

I would greatly appreciate any recommendations on:

What backup software would be most suitable for my needs?
Any specific backup methods or practices to ensure data integrity and easy recovery?

I apologise in advance if this post is too detailed. After lurking and reading a lot of support posts, I got the impression that it might be better to over-supply info and requirements upfront to get the best response rate.
There might just be the perfect system out there to suit my needs so thought I may as well include everything, and if not, I need some places to start. The backup results in the Ubuntu Store App didn't really inspire me, to be honest.
I'm open to any suggestions.

Does this answer your question? Comparison of backup tools

I can remove the close vote if it does not answer your question. So if not, please reply back and also, reply with @mchid at the beginning of the comment so that I'll get a notification.

@mchid I was kinda looking for some tailored advice based on the details in the post rather than a comparison list. I am hoping someone reads this and recognises a good fit.
Thanks for the list, I will check it out - but like I said looking for some tailored advice if possible. If this isn't the right forum to ask for this kind of advice let me know.

I see that Timeshift is listed in the answers linked to by @mchid which would have been my recommendation. It also works well on my Debian 12 instance but haven't tried it to a cloud based resource.

@graham Thanks, I actually looked at Timeshift - but my impression was it was more of a system backup rather than files and cloud. I think it can probably do both, I will check it further though, appreciate the headsup. I assume I won't be able to find the perfect solution for my use case but wanted to put it out there just in case.

I do both... you set that under the Filters tab. A simple user guide is provided here

I read through the guide and it actually ticks a lot boxes. I skipped this one when I first came across it, should have looked deeper. I think this in combo with multcloud.com (to download cloud to local first), is the answer. Thankyou! Happy with this as the answer.

@graham If you post Timeshift as the answer, happy to accept it. Thanks.

Also note that the Comparison of backup tools is a 13 year old thread, while the top answer isn't quite as old but still 2016, which is why I decided to post this topic.

Timeshift` is a reliable maintenance free package for backup and is intuitive in it's use.
Addressing concerns about Timeshift being only for system backups, it is configurable under Settings > Users tab  to include User Home Directories (which are disabled by default) by indicating a requirement to include all files and under the Filters tab to fine-tune Include and Exclude patterns.

Timeshift can be installed using the command:
sudo apt install timeshift

A beginners guide from It's FOSS shows how to backup and restore Linux systems (including Ubuntu) in easy to follow steps.

Thank you appreciate this as I had initially bypassed it not realising it did data backups too.
